# Get the category of wikipedia article in python

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am using the below mentioned code to check the existence of wikipedia page.

```
term = "forensics"
a = urllib.request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+term).getcode()
print(a)
```

If the page exists (i.e. **a == 200**), I want to get the category of the page (i.e., if the category is computer science, engineering etc.). Can we do that in wikipedia api?

Comment: A Google search shows multiple Python packages that handle this.

Comment: What if there are multiple categories?

Comment: check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wikipedia-API, specifically the "how to get page categories" section.

Comment: @Alex I checked. But they do not support conda it seems :(

Comment: @Cyzanfar Thanks a lot. I tried wikipedia api. But it did not support conda.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Having multiple categories is fine for me

Comment: Conda is a package manager. Just Install it with pip

Comment: @Cyzanfar I tried different commands such as `conda install wikipedia-api`, `conda install -c akode wikipedia` etc. However it returns `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:`. Can you please tell me how to install wikipedia api in conda??

Comment: No just use pip

Comment: @Cyzanfar I also did `pip install wikipedia-api` now. However, conda still do not recognise `wikipedia`. Can you please tell me where I am making it wrong?

Comment: @JCena: did you install it in the correct local environment?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I did. Wikipedia works fine outside of conda. But not in conda :( Maybe the python version I have in conda is 3. what are your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot), you can get categories of the page `forensics` :

```
>>> import pywikibot as pw
>>> pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics')
Page(Forensics)
>>> pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').exists()
True
>>> pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').categories()
<pywikibot.data.api.PageGenerator object at 0x7fea9d44ca90>
>>> list(pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').categories())
[Category(Category:Printworthy redirects), Category(Category:Redirects from short names), Category(Category:Redirects mentioned in hatnotes), Category(Category:Redirects with history)]
>>> [i.title() for i in list(pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').categories())]
[u'Category:Printworthy redirects', u'Category:Redirects from short names', u'Category:Redirects mentioned in hatnotes', u'Category:Redirects with history']
```

But I don't think that's what you're looking for. `forensics` is a [redirect page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Redirect). You'll need to get the target page name, and get categories of this new one.

```
>>> pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').isRedirectPage()
True
>>> pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').getRedirectTarget()
Page(Forensic science)
```

Another solution would have been to parse talk pages, for example to get the `Law Enforcement` string and others present in `{{WikiProject ...}}` from [`Talk:Forensic_science`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Talk:Forensic_science&action=edit). Use `page.toggleTalkPage()` to get the new Page object corresponding to the talk page. But unlike the categories, parse talk pages text to get project names is not an official way/that I can advise you, although it might help you to triage it in more general categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer :) However, I am not sure why the categories it returns are not very clear. I was expecting to clear categories such as `science,engineering, computer science` etc. Can you please suggest a way to obtain such clear categories? :)

Comment: First, "forensics" is a redirect to "Forensic science", it's why all categories of this page talk about redirects.

Comment: ... You can use `isRedirectPage()`/`getRedirectTarget()` to get the "real" page to analyze.
Now you'll be able to get more interesting categories.
Second, you can parse the talk page "Talk:Forensic_science" (use `.toggleTalkPage()`) to get `{{WikiProject XXX` if you want a more general classification, but categories are reliable in all articles, they are the ones that can be used everywhere, and this second solution is like a hack.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that let you know if I got any issues :)

Comment: if you have time could you please update your answer with the idea yo ave mentioned above. I do not understand how to do this part. `Second, you can parse the talk page "Talk:Forensic_science" (use .toggleTalkPage()) to get {{WikiProject XXX if you want a more general classification`. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Hello, answer updated. Feel free to ask me if I'm not clear :)

Comment: @framawiki does `pywikibot` supports anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

With [Wikipedia-API](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/) your code may look like this:

```
import wikipediaapi
wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
page = wiki.page('forensics')
print(page.categories)
```

Hopefully it helps.

Edit: I have fixed the link. There was extra `]` at the end. Now it is pointing at https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wikipediaapi'  
`pip install wikipediaapi`  
Error: No matching distributions found for wikipediaapi

Comment: I have fixed the link. There was extra `]`. It should be installed as `pip install wikipedia-api`